# How to increase speed on seek of a binary file?

Tags: vb.net

I am searching all the multiple entrances in a list of UInt64 numbers stored in a binary file, like this :

```
Dim i, j, n, cnt As Integer
Dim a, b As UInt64
Dim reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("c:\file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

n = 1000    
For i = 2 To n
    a = reader.ReadUInt64()
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    cnt = 0
    For j = 1 To i - 1
        b = reader.ReadUInt64()
        If b = a Then
            cnt += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Apparently, sequential reading of the stream is very fast, but every return to origin is very time consuming. How can I optimize efficiency?

Comment: After you comment to my answer, I've been thinking about this. Why to you set `n=1000` if the files could  have multiple GB?

Comment: Please consider that size of the binary file is huge (several Gb) and most of the values inside are different one to each other.

Comment: n = 1000 was just for example ! its value comes from the writing process before.. it could be something like 7E9..

Comment: I can't get through your example. Currently your just repeat the same process n times, and value a is always the same?

Comment: no, a is the value taken at the end of a reading cycle of increasing size, so the value is different every time !

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
Dim i, j, n, cnt As Integer
Dim a As UInt64
Dim dict as new Dictionary(Of UInt64, Integer)
Dim reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("c:\file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

n = 1000    
For i = 2 To n
    a = reader.ReadUInt64()
    if dict.ContainsKey(a) then
      dict(a) = dict(a) + 1
    else
      dict(a) = 1
    end if
Next
```

Comment: No, since the dictionary is stored in memory, isn't it?Take note that size of binary file can be several Gb (that's why I cannot perform in-memory search..)

Comment: A very interesting problem then. You should add the the information provided in the comment to the question though. I believe it's necessary to get a good answer.